# How to append array value in magento session?

Tags: magento-1.9, array, core-session

Just I want to append array value in magento session data

```
    Mage::getSingleton( 'core/session' )->setData( 'createArrayDefault', array(3));
    Mage::getSingleton( 'core/session' )->setData( 'createArrayDefault', array(2));

print_r(Mage::getSingleton( 'core/session' )->getData('createArrayDefault'));
```

It  displays `array(0=>2)` and override `3`value from array
    But I want this `array(0=>2,0=>3)`;

When I print magento session data and print,it overrides array `3` value but I want both values in session data.How  to append values in session data.

Answer (score 2):

Setting data to your session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session->setData('createArrayDefault', array(3));
```

If you need later append values to that session data array:

```
$data = $session->getData('createArrayDefault'); 
$session->setData(array_merge(array(3), $data));
```

Comment: its not working